# Find Specific value from multivalued field in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

```
{
     Name : "A";
     Id:["4","205","105"];
    },
    {
     Name : "B";
     Id:["4","205"];
    },
    {
     Name : "C";
     Id:["205"];
    },
    {
     Name : "D";
     Id:["205","205"];
    },
```

I have sample data like above where Id is multivalued field.

Now I have to find Only that result in output where Id = 205.
Accepted output name will be C and D.

Comment: Add an additional field that only contains the unique values for the list and a second field that contains the number of tokens in that field. Query for `id_unique_count:1 AND id_unique:205`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Can you please suggest the approach how to store unique value and unique count in new field ?

Comment: That would depend on how you're indexing content right now. If you're sending content for indexing from your own application, do it directly when creating the document to send to Solr. If you don't control the indexing application yourself you can use an update processor with `CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory` and `UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory`.

Comment: <field name="Id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

This is my multivalued Field.
I want count of this field in same application in this field
<field name="Id_count" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
And Store Unique value in Same application in this field
<field name="Unique_Id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

Than how to Update both field. Can you share the code for schema.xml and solrconfig.xml ?

Comment: Add relevant details to your question; you still haven't explained how you're indexing content now - since that could determine the easiest path to achieving your goal. You don't need to do any changes to your schema to have an update processor run; you configure that for each request handler and define them in `solrconfig.xml` - if you can't change your indexing code (or want to keep everything in Solr), that's the way to do. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/update-request-processors.html for examples and add what you've tried to your question.

Comment: I Have One field in schema.xml Which Contain Many Value.
<field name="Id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

I need copy Unique Value  from this field to another Field and  and Get count of that field in another field.

So, What I need to create new field in schema for store both Unique Value and Count value ?

And How to implement both process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fq = Id:([* TO 204 ][205 TO *])`.
In these query only that values comes which have Id : 205.